# My never dying didital clock

Tags: engine, vw

Why would my clock and Odom digital lights stay on even when car is off and when jump starting it the cables correct you still get spark

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please edit your question to include what type of VW (year/model) your car is? Also, with the spark happening for jump starting a vehicle, this is not uncommon to happen, though the intensity of the spark may be in question. It sounds like you have a significant draw on your system which is draining your battery. Any additional information you might have would be greatly appreciated (like how long it's been going on; did it start after a certain event; etc).

Comment: So its a vw jetta and 1999 GLS model but as long as I've had it it never went dead except the other day I guess I left the lights on part way but my issue was a lot of spark when trying to jump it and we assumed maybe my dash lights digital clock and odometer stay on even after key is turned off cigarette lighter and on drivers side every once in a while going around corners it will ding like when door is open checked fuses all good there also

Comment: If you had a lot of sparks while trying to jump it, are you sure you didn't have the jumpers the wrong way? This could have caused you issues. A lot of *strange* issues.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I had the cables right. What would cause the dash lights to stay on when the car is off  no key in the ignition at all? Like every once in a while the ding and my abs light won't go off but I just had to replace my CV joint and the steering wheel speed sensor and the wiring harness cause it died on me one day while driving it and I couldn't get it started again so it sat for a year at least in all kinds of weather  so I'm trying to figure out what did it so it don't happen again

Comment: I think you need an automotive electrical/electronics specialist or a capable mechanic to diagnose/troubleshoot unusual problems since it never occurred until recently. Vehicles age, wear and tear creep in, sometimes creating unusual issues like yours. Good repair shops can determine where the problem lies since it can be anywhere; main ignition relay sticking, body control module driving the odometer, faulty instrument panel, damaged wiring, etc. An expert can find the source of electrical problems. No one here is clairvoyant and would require extensive back and forth discussions.

Comment: the sparks on the jumper cable are there because the discharged battery is discharged too much (to test this - can you switch your headlights/does any light come on on your dashboard, but the car won't start? in this case the battery is discharged but not fully, there may still be sparks, but jump starting is ok; if nothing works, you should not jump start, the wire can catch fire because of the high amp flowing from the jump start battery to the empty one - in this case you should take the battery out and charge it with an appropriate charger or purchase a new battery)